# Windows 10. Удалить папку старого пользователя и создать свою

Tags: windows, windows-10

Купил б\у ноут с установленной Windows 10. Предыдущий владелец, перед продажей удалил свою учетную запись. Я поставил свою (локальную). Но в папке пользователей никаких изменений не произошло. В папке "Пользователи" по-прежнему присутствует папка с названием его учетной записью, а папка с моей учетной записью не появилась. В эту папку по-прежнему ведут все быстрые ссылки с сайдбара, новые ссылки из вновь установленных программ(Sublime Text, например)

Как это все исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте после покупки БУ ноута отформатировал его и винду переставил бы

Comment: @tym32167, согласен. Но меня смущает отсутствие установочного диска и кодов активации.  Семерку я бы сразу снес)

Comment: Я не спец в вопросе, но я на своих ноуте и стационарнике обновил 7ку до 10, и видимо на них ключ куда то а биос прописался, так как я форматировал диски, переставлял 10ку несколько раз и активация сама подхватывалась. Образ установки можно с MS скачать, у них специальная тулза для этого есть.

Comment: @tym32167, благодарю. Пойду искать инфо.

Comment: Единожды активированная 10 при переустановке на тот же компьютер активируется автоматически, информация об активации хранится на серверах MS.

Comment: @Yaant можно пруф? Не видел в нете такой инфы

Comment: @tym32167 [On Windows 10, the activation process can also generate a "digital entitlement", which allows the operating system's hardware and license status to be saved to the activation servers, so that the operating system's license can automatically be restored after a clean installation without the need to enter a product key.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Product_Activation#After_grace_period)

Comment: @Yaant вот это здорово, спасибо!

Comment: Прошу вас переустановить Windows, во избежание проблем в дальнейшем

Answer (score -1):

Зайди в gode mode. Это делается так создаёшь папку и вместо названия пишешь:
GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
У тебя вместо папки появляется файл с настройками. В нём ищешь Параметры учетных записей. Удаляешь учётную запись пред. владельца (если она существует), добавляешь новую и работаешь с ней.